# Primitive Recursive Functions

Tags: calculus, logic, recursive-algorithms, transfinite-recursion

I would like to show that the function $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ defined by $f(n)=p_n$ where $p_n$ is the $n+1$ prime number is primitive recursive. The fact is that I just manage to show it is $μ$ recursive using Kleene operator and I don't see any way to avoid using it. 
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is your class's definition of primitive recursive? Also, what theorems do you have to prove things are primitive recursive? In particular, have you seen that "bounded search" is primitive recursive?

Comment: we defined the class of primitive recursive functions as the smallest class containing the function 0, successor (we're in the language of arithmetic), the projections on the i-th cohordinate and closed under composition and primitive recursion. I'm not sure I know what you mean by "bounded search" but if you mean the bounded minimization through Kleene operator than I know that it is closed under that operation too. In addition, we've seen it is closed under bounded quantificators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider (heuristically)

$$
f(0) = 2\\
f(n+1) = \text{the least $x \leq (2*f(n))$ such that $x > f(n)$ and $x$ is prime}
$$

It is a theorem of arithmetic that for every $k$, there is at least one prime between $k$ and $2k$. Thus we know we can find a prime between $f(n)$ and $2 f(n)$. The least such number will, of course, be the next prime.

I leave it to you to formalize the above idea, but as a hint:

Show

$$
g(r) = \text{the least $x \leq 2r$ such that $x > r$ and $x$ is prime}
$$

is primitive recursive (using bounded search), then use it to define $f$ by recursion.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for